# How to return array of specific type instead of generic type in Java8 with streams

Tags: generics, java-8, java-stream

I have the following class definitions:

```
public class Triple<T,U,V> {

    private T t;
    private U u;
    private V v;

    public Triple(T t, U u, V v){
        this.t  = t;
        this.u = u;
        this.v  = v;
    }

    public T t(){
        return t;
    }

    public U u(){
        return u;
    }

    public V v(){
        return v;
    }
}
```

as well as

```
public class Tuple <T,U>{

    private T t;
    private U u;

    public Tuple(T t, U u){
        this.t = t;
        this.u = u;
    }

    public T t(){
        return t;
    }

    public U u(){
        return u;
    }
}
```

and finally

```
public class State {
    private String name;

    public State(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I want to create a method that takes a variable number of triples as parameters and returns a value of type `Tuple<Tuple<State,String>,State>[]` - that is an array of Tuples where each tuple has as its first member a Tuple of a State and a String and as its second member a State. The method that I have written and which doesn't work is the following:

```
public static Tuple<Tuple<State,String>,State>[] mkRelationOne(Triple<String,String,String>...tr){
    return Arrays.stream(tr).map(
            x->new Tuple<Tuple<State,String>,State>(
                new Tuple<State,String>(
                    new State(x.t()), x.u()
                ),
                new State(x.v())
            )
        ).toArray(Tuple<Tuple<State,String>,State>[]::new);
}
```

The error message is `Cannot create a generic array of type Tuple<Tuple<State,String>,State>`. How is it a generic array if it has a type, the type being `Tuple<Tuple<State,String>,State>`? And how can I fix this so that it returns the array that I want it to to return? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create a `generic` *array* there, that is not supported in java. An array can not be declared with type parameters.

That is you can not *create* a generic array, but you can *declare* one:

```
public static Tuple<Tuple<State, String>, State>[] mkRelationOne(Triple<String, String, String>... tr) {
    return (Tuple<Tuple<State, String>, State>[]) Arrays.stream(tr).map(
            x -> new Tuple<>(
                    new Tuple<>(
                            new State(x.t()), x.u()),
                    new State(x.v())))
            .toArray(Tuple[]::new);
}
```

This will work, but will generate a warning.